# how to set a specific sql command into selected column in table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

using java in netbeans, i want to get the data using this sql command below and load these data in a specific column in my table "jTable1". in the fifth column for example

```
 sql = "SELECT SUM(`msareffishmarket`.`Amount`) FROM `manfz`.`msareffishmarket`\n"

  stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
              jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```